# Transform New Line to Space MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How to transform new line to space in mysql?

```
lot 1
road 1
12345 USA
```

to become

```
lot 1 road 1 12345 USA
```

I tried

```
select trim(both '\r\n' from address) address from registration
```

but still new line is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `REPLACE()`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(address,"\n"," ") address from registration;
```

This is assuming *nix-style line termination. Use `\r\n` for windows.

Comment: aww this is good. thank you so much. i will accept this answer soon as i cant accept answer within 8 minutes. :)

Answer (score 1):

[TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) will only remove the start or end  (prefix or suffix) of whatever you give it.

There is, however, a MySQL command to find/[replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
SELECT REPLACE(address,'\n',' ') FROM registration;
```

where the parameters are:

- input (i.e. your field)
- search string
- replacement